# Retrieving concentration values from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, algorithm, water

I am using a chlorophyll-a algorithm to retrieve chlorophyll-a and turbidity concentrations using different algorithms for a lake using Sentinel 2A (S2_SR).  How can I determine the output concentration values from the algorithms and know what units they are in?

For the code, I am first masking the water by using an advanced water extraction index (AWEI) and then applying the chl on top of the mask. The code I am using is below:

```
/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

// Map the function over one year of data and take the median.
// Load Sentinel-2 TOA reflectance data.
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filterDate('2022-06-01', '2022-06-28')
 // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
 .filterBounds(roi)
  .map(maskS2clouds)
  
print (collection)

//RGB generation
var median = collection.median()
var clipped = median.clipToCollection(roi)
var para = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min:0, max: 0.3}


//Mask water using AWEI
var AWEI = clipped.expression('4 *(green - swir1) - 0.25 * nir + 2.75 * swir2',
{
  'green': clipped.select('B3'),
  'nir': clipped.select ('B8'),
  'swir1':clipped.select('B11'),
  'swir2':clipped.select ('B12')
});

var awei_Masked = AWEI.updateMask(AWEI.gt(0.0));


//Specifiy 3BDA (Castro et al. 2020 - Table 16) 
//(Can swtich beteween B7 and B8 as they are both in NIR range)
var cheq1 = clipped.expression ('((26.795 * ((1/B4)-(1/B5))*B8) + 7.134) ',
{

  B5: clipped.select('B5'),
  B7:clipped.select('B7'),
  B4:clipped.select('B4'),
  B8:clipped.select('B8'),
});

//Display chl-a on masked AWEI
var Chl1 = cheq1.updateMask(AWEI);

//Specifiy band ratio G/R
var cheq2 = clipped.expression ('1*(B3/B4) ',
{

  B3: clipped.select('B3'),
  B4:clipped.select('B4'),
 
});

//Display chl-a on masked AWEI
var Chl2 = cheq2.updateMask(AWEI);


/* TURBIDITY*/

//Specifiy NDTI
var turbeq1 = clipped.expression ('((B4-B3)/(B4+B3)) ',
{

  B3: clipped.select('B3'),
  B4:clipped.select('B4'),
 
});

//Display chl-a on masked AWEI
var Turb1 = turbeq1.updateMask(AWEI);

//Display Chl1
var NDCIpal = {min: 6.8, max: 10, palette: ['0c2aff','00ff14','ff0000']};
Map.addLayer(Chl1, NDCIpal, '3BDA');

//Display Chl2
var NDCIpal = {min: 6.8, max: 10, palette: ['0c2aff','00ff14','ff0000']};
Map.addLayer(Chl2, NDCIpal, 'Band ratio');

//Display Turbidity
var NDCIpal = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['blue','green','red']};
Map.addLayer(Turb1, NDCIpal, 'NDTI');

//Display RGB
Map.setCenter(152.5542, -27.3083, 12);
Map.addLayer(clipped, para, 'RGB');
```

Comment: You know that above code doesn't work. Don't you? The reason is because you are using **clipToCollection** method instead only **clip** method.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and that correction! However it was working for me but I understand the clip method is appropriate. Are you aware of a way to determine the output concentrations from the algorithms used and what units they are in (e.g. ug/L)?